# Event Registration in Drupal 7 (Paid, using Ubercart, multiple attendees)

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-modules, registration, ubercart

I've set up a D7 site with events and paid event signups. We must use Ubercart and support seems to be leaning towards Commerce. I've had trouble with the Registration module working with D7 Ubercart and have finally found success using Signups with "[Ubercart signup integration for Drupal 7](https://github.com/sfyn/uc_signup_d7)"... which I got from Github, so it's not official. I was happy, UNTIL we needed to collect signup information for more than one event attendee per purchase.

How can I enable/capture field data for a second person's event registration?

Comment: did you get any solution for this?